Can an Arista switch be programmed to bounce all ports after successful boot?
After a power outage and restore, we typically have a large number of offline devices. I believe I've tracked down the cause to this: The ethernet switch is one of the slowest devices to boot after the power is restored. Many DHCP client implementations time out after a few minutes and stop sending DISCOVER packets. An easy solution is to bounce the switch port (shut, then no shut) which revitalizes the DHCP client. Is there a way to automate this in the switch config so that after the switch is fully booted (or some other configurable condition) it bounces a group of ports?

What research have you done regarding this, and what have you tried?

I've tried googling and skimming the Arista user manual for some kind of event-based trigger for scripts but I'm not really sure what I'm looking for. I just have no idea if this is in the realm of possibility.

Have you looked at this? https://www.arista.com/en/um-eos/eos-command-line-interface-cli Rather than event based triggers, you should be looking for a scheduler and/or a scripting engine, and this page deals with both those. UPDATE: and it appears to have an event based engine too, but if you're looking for something to run after a switch boot, you're probably looking for a scheduled task rather than an event task still.

Thanks! That is very helpful.
